# Why is my SQL query returning an array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got a table of users each with a unique ID. When I try and fetch their ID for the session it returns an array of two IDs for some reason.

So in the following code, $_SESSION['userid'] becomes an array containing two instances of the same ID.

I can't figure out why though...

```
$_SESSION['userid'] = getUserID($_POST['username']);


function getUserID($username)
{
    include 'db.inc.php';
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = '". $username. "'";
        $s   = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $s->bindValue(':username', $username);
        $s->execute();
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error = 'Error getting userid for '.$username . '....error: '.$e;
        include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/database/includes/pages/error.html.php";
        exit();
    }
    $row = $s->fetch();
    return $row;

}
```

Comment: did you check your db? maybe its actually contains the same object twice?

Comment: Not a solution, but your SQL statement is incorrect. In order to bind the parameter with PDO, it should look like `SELECT id FROM user WHERE username = :username`

Comment: To clarify, `getUserID()` is returning an associative array? Can you post the contents of that array (do `print_r($row)`)? What are you expecting it to return?

Comment: @DimaGoltsman, the database is in testing phase so just contains 2 users with unique ids(primary key) and unique usernames.

Comment: @Blowski Array ( [id] => 2 [0] => 2 )   .... expecting it to just return the id e.g. 1 or 2 not an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is in your `$s->fetch()`. By default PDO fetches an array indexed by both field and number, e.g. `$row['id']` and `$row[0]` Try this:

```
$row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $row['id'];
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php for more information.

Answer (score 2):

`PDOStatement::fetch()` defaults to returning `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`:

> returns an array indexed by both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your result set

(Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

You need to do:

```
$row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$s->fetch()` is returning an object. You need to modify it to return an associative array:

```
$s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing wrong with `$result = $sth->fetch();` You have missed `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` which returns an array indexed by column name as returned in your result set.

So you must use the code like

```
$row = $s->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```